# Unable to install python3-dev ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, apt, python, dependencies, python3

When I tried to install `python3-dev` using `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` I got the following message

```
python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python3.4-dev (>= 3.4.0-0~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried installing dependencies `libpython3-dev` then I got this message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.4-dev : Depends: libpython3.4-stdlib (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1) but 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpython3.4 (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1) but 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However both the dependencies are already installed.I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

When I ran the `apt-cache policy python3.4` I got

```
    python3.4:
    Installed: 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1
  Candidate: 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     3.4.0-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Which ubuntu version? Try `apt-get clean all` then try again.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: How did you invoke the command? Make sure your system is up-to-date.

Comment: What command? I used `sudo apt-get clean all`

Comment: I mean when u try to install.

Comment: I've added in the new edit. I've used `apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: Ok `apt-get upgrade`. Make sure system is up to date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30086/discussion-between-ilovecamelcase-and-aizuddin-zali).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to wait for the Ubuntu developers to re-upload Python 3.4.3 to the updates repository. This should happen any day now. Keep your eyes on [bug #1348954](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/python3-stdlib-extensions/+bug/1348954).

Edit: Fixed. Installing `python3-dev` works again.

Answer (score 2):

Okay So I went through [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1503382) and temporarily solved the problem by forcefully downgrading my python

```
apt-get install -y \
  python3.4=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 \
  python3.4-minimal=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 \
  libpython3.4-stdlib=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1 \
  libpython3.4-minimal=3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1
```

Edit:
After this reinstall `stdlib` as it misses some libraries.
Removing python3 might remove some packages of your desktop environment reinstall the desktop environment in that case.

I had some issues with lightdm after this. Before removing print the removed packages and reinstall them with new python 3