# cant install python3 on ubuntu

Tags: python3

I try to download python on ubuntu I get the following errors:

```
ali@CCVL-4GPU:/media/work$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpeas-1.0-0 : Depends: libpython3.4 (>= 3.4~b1) but it is not going to be installed
 python3 : Depends: python3.4 (>= 3.4.0-0~) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python3-minimal (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3.4-dev (>= 3.4.0-0~) but it is not going to be installed
 rhythmbox-mozilla : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 sessioninstaller : Depends: aptdaemon (>= 0.30) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

i tried everything on [Unable to install python3-dev ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683555/unable-to-install-python3-dev-ubuntu)

and still get the same error. Any tips?

Update 1

when i run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

i get

```
:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apg app-install-data apport-symptoms apt-xapian-index cups-pk-helper
  duplicity gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0
  gkbd-capplet gnome-control-center-shared-data intel-gpu-tools laptop-detect
  libapparmor-perl libc6-dbg libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl libgnome-control-center1
  libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 librsync1 libtimezonemap1 python-debtagshw
  python-lockfile python-lxml python-oneconf python-pycurl python-xapian
  qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin run-one screen signon-keyring-extension
  syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy tmux ubuntu-extras-keyring
  ubuntu-system-service
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dh-python python3-apt rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
Suggested packages:
  python3-apt-dbg python-apt-doc gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gnome-codec-install gnome-control-center
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dh-python python3-apt rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 264 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 190 kB/580 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,851 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main dh-python all 1.20140128-1ubuntu8.2 [51.1 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main python3-apt amd64 0.9.3.5ubuntu2 [139 kB]
Fetched 190 kB in 0s (1,144 kB/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package dh-python.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'screen-resolution-extra' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 354932 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dh-python_1.20140128-1ubuntu8.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dh-python (1.20140128-1ubuntu8.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-apt.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apt_0.9.3.5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-apt (0.9.3.5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rhythmbox.
Preparing to unpack .../rhythmbox_3.0.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rhythmbox (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist.
Preparing to unpack .../rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist_3.0.2-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rhythmbox-plugins.
Preparing to unpack .../rhythmbox-plugins_3.0.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rhythmbox-plugins (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apt:
 python3-apt depends on python3 (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-apt depends on python3 (<< 3.5); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:
 rhythmbox depends on python3 (<< 3.5); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 rhythmbox depends on python3 (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist:
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (>= 3.0); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist depends on rhythmbox (<< 3.1); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on python3 (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on python3 (<< 3.5); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 rhythmbox-plugins depends on rhythmbox (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
 dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-apt
 rhythmbox
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist
 rhythmbox-plugins
 dh-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I'm usuing Ubuntu 14
and i cant duplicate the link David you send me because when i run the commands it does not end it dies as it comes across python 3 packages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```